# Quickly Redrawing in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, user-interface, cocoa

I have an OSX application code base that was started a few years back so all of it is written in Cooca. It has several UI components that are updated multiple times a second. Most (if not all) of the components redraw about 60 times a second. All the components are refreshed on non-main threads (core audio, core video, NSTimers, etc.).

Recently it's become apparent that the application is struggling to keep up with itself. Several of the UI components are refreshing at a mere fraction of what they are supposed to. I think this is due to how many various components we're trying to update and the frequency of which we're calling the updates

Does anyone know of some ways to optimize the drawing components? I'm asking specifically related to Cocoa usage, not general threading/UI best practices. For instance, I've read about using NSOperationQueues, but I do not know enough about the way they work to identify if they could help solve our performance issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what and how are you drawing? Are these custom views, custom controls, user-interactive components? I guess, first and foremost: do these things need to be drawing at 60 FPS? Are they updating between frames, or are you forcibly redrawing even when it's not necessary? (`NSOperationQueue` will not help you draw any faster, unless the slowness is because you're doing a lot of work on the main thread, blocking UI drawing.)

Comment: Everything is pretty much a custom control of some sort. We have several buttons and dynamic components that represent real time state feedback. Short story is we're making a media player tool that has audio level feedback and timecode/video updates. So yes, drawing 60 FPS is pretty much required. I believe most components are set to redraw on their own based on 'set...'.

Comment: Are you doing the drawing work in `drawRect:`, using layers, etc.? The best way to draw efficiently is to not draw at all. :) If you have parts of your views which don't change with time, it's very efficient to stick those in layers (which will never change), and do your custom drawing in other layers. The layer hierarchy will very efficiently composite these changes (as opposed to redrawing your entire very every frame at 60 FPS, if that's what you're doing now).

Comment: That's a good idea. Some of the components draw with layers, although I'm not sure if all of them do (learning over the course of time and all). Can you make labels (NStextFields) that work this way too?

Comment: Default Cocoa controls are implemented pretty efficiently; they are not redrawing at 60 FPS unless you are changing them that fast. An `NSTextField`, when left alone, will actually not redraw at all (because it doesn't have to — it's not changing). Basically, I'd say your biggest concern is in any view you have that overrides `drawRect:`; unless it doesn't change at all, it's highly likely that too much redrawing is being done there.

Comment: Most `drawRect:` implementations I've seen ignore the rect parameter and redraw the whole view. When done this way, it's pretty inefficient. More so, however, `drawRect:` generally doesn't give the compositing system much to work with (you essentially just hand the system a bitmap context and tell it "here, draw this as-is"); working with layers gives you more flexibility, and has the bonus of generally being more performant (e.g. no need to re-draw backgrounds, things that haven't changed, etc.).

Comment: I have one addition to make: You do not need to update your views at 60 frames per second. Some monitors aren't even capable of displaying that. Instead, use 'CADisplayLink' to draw. It uses the monitors refresh rate. So separate the logic of your media playback from the UI and only redraw when necessary..

Comment: @mangerlahn `CADisplayLink` is iOS only. On macOS, there's `CVDisplayLink`, but it's not as straightforward as `CADisplayLink` is.

Comment: You are comletely right. That was more of a typo. Thanks!

That is true, but it can be used, it just needs some time to understand the concept.

Comment: Another tip: Use opacity where you can. If you have views that aren't using transparency, make them opaque. The system then doesn't need to look "behind" the view to see what colours are drawn there. This can be a big performance hit.

Comment: @bhawley Instead of continuing further here in comments, how would you like this question to be answered? Do these tips suffice, or are you looking for something deeper?